# Configure macports to build and install to user-specified directory?

Tags: macports, imagemagick

I want several machines on my network to be able to use some libraries installed with MacPorts (the libraries are ImageMagick and its dependent image libs).

I do not want to build and install for each machine -- is it possible to tell macports to install to say `/Volumes/network_drive/macports`? Then, I'll just configure all of my machines to add `/Volumes/network_drive/macports/bin` to `$PATH`.

Is this possible, or even good practice?

Answer (score 0):

A better way might be to make /opt a link to /Volumes/network_drive/macports on all the machines so the ports only needs updating by one machine but are visible on all.

Another way is chnage the port root to do that see source install in [Macports install docs](http://www.macports.org/install.php)

Comment: Good idea. As far as getting macports to build into `/Volumes/netowrk_drive/macports`, I should build macports itself with `./configure --prefix /Volumes/network_drive/macports` -- sound correct?

Comment: Thats what the docs say - and does make sense re configure - although I would not be surprised if there is a port that fails due to hard coding + those which end up in /Applications